# Unix Timestamp calculate date with DST in mind

Tags: php, timestamp, dst

How do I calculate the unix timestamp of yesterday where we keep the dst in mind?

Normally I would do `$timestamp - 86400` but that does not work when yesterday was without DST and today is.

Comment: `strtotime('Yesterday')`?

Comment: yeah, but then I would have to convert to english time first. I was hoping to skip that step

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `$timestamp - 86400` means *timestamp minus 86400* seconds. That value is not dependent on timezones. What result do you expect?

Comment: Unix timestamps don't have a concept of yesterday. It represents an instant in time.

Comment: So converting it to normal English time, use strtotime and then convert it back to unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class and you'll have to specifiy the Timezone of England (BST) in the Timestring. Like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime('Yesterday BST');
$timestamp = $dt->getTimestamp(); // first second of 'yesterday'
```

The example above will respect daylight saving times.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$startTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')-1, date('Y'));     
$endTime = mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d')-1, date('Y'));
```

This is from:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1861-mktime-timestamp-yesterday-last-month-etc